# How to resolve "ORA-00939: too many arguments for function " error?

Tags: oracle

I have the following query:
Firstly I have created a type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_id IS VARRAY(50000) OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

I am executing the below query:

```
SELECT B.ID,
       LISTAGG (A.NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.NAME),
       Assignednames,
       B.IsManager
FROM LOCATION A
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES B
    ON A.LOCATIONID = B.LOCATIONID
WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT * FROM table(array_id('244410','PERF507' )) )
GROUP BY B.ID,
         B.IsManager
```

Now, when I am executing the abovequery, it's working fine when the number of elements inside array_id('244410','PERF507') is less.But in real environment I have around 15K records; and its giving the below error:

```
ORA-00939: too many arguments for function
```

Now, I tried changing the type:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_id IS VARRAY(50000) OF VARCHAR2(50);
to CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_id IS VARRAY(500000) OF VARCHAR2(20); and other combinations but still getting the same error.

I am sure its due to the sizing, but not able to get the correct calculations!
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `array_id` defined, and is this query really what is being run?

Comment: Yes, it's the same query.array_id is defined for the same client and its working absolutely fine when the number of elements inside is less, as mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you can use `array_id`, your custom type, in this way in a regular query.  You might have to do this from dynamic SQL.

Comment: As I said it's working fine for less number!

Comment: That it doesn't work with 2 or more entries means that it's not behaving as expected.  So you should rethink your approach.  Or, stick with your current query which does not work.

Comment: Not 2 or more..I think its working upto 1000..I have given 2 as example!

Comment: I imagine it's related to [the restriction on expression lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19003103/266304). The collection can be bigger but you can't create/populate it with a list of more than 1000 items. So you need to look at how you're creating that list - comma-separating 15K values clearly isn't the way to go. Where are the values coming from, and where is the real query called from (e.g. over JDBC)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Oracle DB, any insertion with more than 1,000 entries will throw ORA-00939. I found this by having a script generate polygons from lots on Oracle Spatial DB.

You may be able to use `EXISTS` to solve what you're looking for.